# Heroku Error Deleting a Post in Production: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am trying to delete a post in my app. It's working fine in localhost but when i pushed to heroku it's not working. I get an error saying "Something went wrong , Please check the logs". Here is my code:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! , except: [:index,:show,:search]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit,:update,:destroy]




  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    else
    @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(post_id: @post.id)

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end


  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description,:image,:all_tags)
    end

    def check_user
      if  current_user.id != @post.user_id
      redirect_to root_path , alert: "Sorry this Post belongs to someone else"
    end
    end

end
```

**The Logs**

[image]

[image]

**view/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<h3>Posts</h3>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><h4><%=link_to post.title , post%></h4></td>
        <td><%=raw tag_links(post.all_tags)%></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <%end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**models/post.rb**

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings 
  #Paperclip Installation
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]


  def all_tags=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(",").map do |name|
      Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end

def all_tags
  self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
end

def self.tagged_with(name)
  Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts
end

end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151026124712) do

      create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "title"
        t.text     "description"
        t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.string   "tags"
        t.string   "image_file_name"
        t.string   "image_content_type"
        t.integer  "image_file_size"
        t.datetime "image_updated_at"
      end

      create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.text     "comment"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.integer  "post_id"
      end

      create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "post_id"
        t.integer  "tag_id"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end

      add_index "taggings", ["post_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_post_id"
      add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"

      create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end

      create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "name"
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

      create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "votable_id"
        t.string   "votable_type"
        t.integer  "voter_id"
        t.string   "voter_type"
        t.boolean  "vote_flag"
        t.string   "vote_scope"
        t.integer  "vote_weight"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
      add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"

    end
```

Comment: Please do not link images, please just copy and paste zur logs into the question. That makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Show us the `db/schema.rb` file.

Comment: i included the Schema and the Post model too.

Answer (score 1):

As the error log says, there are foreign keys related to posts in taggings table, so it does not allow you to delete posts. 
I guess a **post** has many **taggings**, and a **tagging** belongs to a **tag**? In this case, you need to delete all taggings belong to the post you want to delete. The easiest way is adding `dependent: :destroy` to your post model like

```
# models/post.rb
has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: i tried that but still the error keeps showing. I have updated my Question and included the model file and the Schema too.

Answer (score 1):

You have some records in `Taggings` table which referenced to `Post` record.

So you have several options -

- `has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy`

Or you can change yours migration:

- `add_foreign_key :taggins, :posts, on_delete: :cascade` (you can add this in database migration)

[Described here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html)

Comment: Thanks. i tried the first option but it the error still the same. The second option you mean i add that in the Schema file ??

Comment: I think it is not good idea to edit Schema file - just add it to migration file